# Problems reading a file into a struct

Tags: c++, struct, binary

I have defined this struc to read a binary file

```
struct cabecera{            
  unsigned long time;
    short lrec;
    short eddimdat;
    short edmaxdat;
    short edncn;
    short estindefmax;
    long maxiedisc;
  long edbuit;
    long edusat;
    short estindefusat;
    long libdoff;
    long vidoff;
    long dgoff;
  long estindefoff;
    long estinoff;
    long sedoff;
  long esdoff;
    int libvers;
    long offie;
    long tiueoff;
};
```

I have a class that extends from fstream to read the data

```
open(fNombre.c_str(),ios::in|ios::binary);
if(fail()||bad()) return;

int pos = 160 ;
cabecera cb={};
seekg(pos,ios::beg);
read((char*)&cb, sizeof(cb));
```

But the variable maxiedisc gets a wrong value (1052835858) and the rest on the variables from here too
If I read this variable without the structure, the value I obtain is correct(1200000)

```
int tmLong = sizeof(long);
int tmULong = sizeof(unsigned long);
int tmShort = sizeof(short);   
int pos = 160 + tmULong  + (tmShort*5);
seekg(pos,ios::beg);
long maxiedisc;                        
read((char*)&maxiedisc, tmLong);
```

What is the problem with the structure? Why I obtain different results?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly you have *padding* in your struct. The compiler has placed two extra bytes between the estindefmax and maxiedisc members. This is why reading directly into a struct is a bad idea, unless you wrote the file with the exact same struct.

Do it your second way, without the struct. Fill the struct in later if that is what you need.

Comment: While I completely agree that this is a very bad idea indeed, many compilers provide a way to create structures without padding (usually precisely for serialization purposes). See, for example, `__attribute__((packed))` in GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing files directly from memory to disk is not portable.

Some of the problems you may have are

- **Memory padding**. (Compiler dependent) You can use `#pragma pack` (vs) to avoid this but those structures will be used by CPu in a more inefficient way.
- **Endian-ess**. Integer types can be stored in Little-Ending or Big-Endian format (Platform dependent). Can be converted by using `boost::endian` family of functions
- **Save complex data structures** (STL list, vector, etc)
- **struct versioning**. Load an older version of a struct in a newer program.

The right approach is to use a serialization library that already encapsulate all this problems (like `Boost::serialization` or google's `ProtoBuff`) or if the overhead of a library is too big for you to write a little serializer yourself. It's easier than it sounds. Just write two member functions (save/load) that writes/reads members to/from a stream. You should handle yourself endian-ess and versioning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the padding of your compiler. It will add padding bytes to your structure making it bigger than you would expect.
Since you did not mention which compiler you use: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is how it is done on msvc. If I  remember  corrctly  gcc has the same syntax. But Inever tried it.

Comment: Thanks to all!
I't was the struct padding. I found how to disable in Borland Builder and now it works ok!

Answer (score 0):

looks like padding issues

to read directly into a struct with gcc try

```
struct my_struct {
    /* ... */
} __attribute__((packed));
```

this ensures, that no padding is used

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @john the problem seems to be the struct padding.

You have two solutions to get rid of the padding, first one is to write each struct component one by one (but in structs of that size is not the best way) the second one is disable the padding as suggested by other users.

```
#ifndef LINUX
#pragma pack(1)
#endif
struct cabecera
{
    // your stuff...
}__attribute__((packed));
#else
};
#endif
```

PS: don't mix languages on your code, it looks silly ;) "*si programas en inglés, usa el inglés para nombrar variables y datos*"

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Google [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to do the serialization/unserialization of a struct for you. This approach is much safer and works across compiler and system boundaries. The alternative would be to serialize each field individually. Packing is sometimes the quickest option, but has problems with compiler compatibility and binary compatibility between systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
// struct definition
#pragma push
```